# Position Span Elements 50% from Top of Image

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I am creating a slideshow in JavaScript and would like to position the controls (the next and previous buttons) relative to the image so that it's 50% from the top of the image.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://c4.staticflickr.com/8/7495/16322256485_08ee0ee36f_z.jpg" />
                <figcaption>This is an example of a really long caption. Here I go. Do I wrap to a second line? Wrap wrap wrap wrap. Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8584/16136057529_e7b64928d0_z.jpg" />
                <figcaption>Insert caption</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7474/16120961661_8dc12962dd_z.jpg" />
                <figcaption>Insert caption</figcaption>
            </figure>

        </div><!-- end slideshow -->
```

The spans that I'm positioning are inserted with JavaScript above the closing div for the slideshow.

The original plan was to position the buttons relative to the slideshow div. However, if the caption spans multiple lines, then the slideshow grows in height and the buttons move.

I would like the position of the buttons to be constant in relation to the height of the image. So instead of positioning the spans in relation to the entire slideshow div, which includes the captions, I want it to position itself in relation to the image, regardless of the height of the caption.

I cannot position with pixels because the slideshow must be responsive.

Here is my JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/amykirst/vtsru170/

One idea that I had was to change the HTML by wrapping the image and the spans in a div, like this:

```
<figure>
                <div class="img-contain">
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8584/16136057529_e7b64928d0_z.jpg" />
                </div>
                <figcaption>This is an example of a really long caption. Here I go. Do I wrap to a second line? Wrap wrap wrap wrap. Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap</figcaption>
            </figure>
```

And then have the JavaScript insert the spans inside the "img-contain" div and position it in relation to that div. The JavaScript would need to locate which image is currently being shown and add the spans in each time that the "next" or "previous" button is pushed.

Right now, it adds the buttons once on page load.

I thought that my new solution might be complicating things too much so I wanted to see if there was a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/vtsru170/4/

The trick is to add a `padding-bottom` to the next/previous spans to match the height (according to the aspect ratio) of the image. I used the p tags inside the tag for the button styles.

Comment: What if I don't know what the height of the comments will be? In my example, the first one spanned multiple lines but I don't know if in practice it would have more or less.

Comment: Maybe I should use JavaScript to check the height of the tallest slide and then make the others match?

Comment: The number of lines doesn't matter in this case. Did you notice that(in the fiddle) I've added many lines of text for the first slide?

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at stack overflow on my phone last night and couldn't see the fiddle. Two questions. (1) What is the padding-bottom of the span based on? How is it calculated? I thought that it would be based on the height of its parent element (the slideshow) but it's not. (2) What if I want the controls to be in the center of the image, but I don't know what height the image will be? In your fiddle, the percentage that you used works but if the picture changed in height, then that percentage of 75% would no longer be in the middle.

Comment: For ques. 1, just saw that the padding-bottom is based on the width of the parent element.

Comment: Yes, the images needs to have a common height in this case. This is purely a css based solution. If the images have dynamic height, you need to go with a js solution.